# Automation Error when running Selenium VBA on Excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, automation

I  was running the following code without a problem on a machine with excel 2013.  We recently upgraded to Excel 2019 and the  macro  now returns an **Automation** error. I noticed that the error seems to be in the **driver.start** section , it looks like it's not 'registering' the reference.  I have reinstalled the Selenium add-in , re-pointed the reference,  tried different browsers ( chrome, edge etc)  but to no avail .

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim keyObj As Selenium.keys
Dim IE As Object

Set keyObj = New Selenium.keys

driver.Start "ie"
driver.Window.Maximize
driver.Get "https://www.google.com/"
```

Any suggestions/ ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: tried all the suggestions and failed, until I install .NET 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Try adding Selenium to references (Selenium Type Library).

It solved the error for me.

When you installed Selenium you checked the drivers?
[image]

If you are using Chrome, have you downloaded the same version of chrome driver as your chrome browser version?

First of all, go to control panel and uninstall previous installation of selenium and then follow the steps 1- Download the latest version of chrome and make sure of the version of Chrome from Help >> About Google Chrome. You would see something like that Version *75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (32-bit)*

2- Download the latest version from the [LINK](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/download/v2.0.9.0/SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0.exe)

3- Download the chromedriver from the follwoing [LINK](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) Make sure of the version that suits your chrome version As for the Google Chrome version I posted the most suitable version of chromedriver is ChromeDriver *75.0.3770.140*

Now setup SeleniumBasic >> After setup unzip the chromedriver file *chromedriver_win32.zip* and copy the *chromedriver.exe* to the path of selenium Here's two possibilties: First >> C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic Second >> C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic Copy the *chromedriver.exe* to the SeleniumBasic path

Open new blank excel file >> Press Alt + F11 (Visual Basic Editor) >> Tools >> References >> Selenium Type Library

Insert new module and paste the following code to test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sel As New WebDriver
    
    sel.Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com"
    sel.Get "/"
    Stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by installing MS .Net framework 3.5 (Selenium requires)

Answer (score 3):

Please install thru StartChrome.vbs under

```sh
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Scripts\
```

which lead you proper .Net packages.

which is not correct answer to you, but for someone who are wondering how to start solve this issue.

Selenium team already prepared these kind script

Comment: Required after fresh install of Windows 11 on a newly built computer. The install only included Net Framework 4.8.x, but selenium would not run until I installed Net Framework 3.5 using that vbs script.

Answer (score 2):

I found  a solution to the problem  by following a suggestion on a similar post.
It looks like Selenium requires MS .Net framework 3.5 . As soon as I add it , the Macro started to work.  Because it was a new laptop with  Excel 2019  on it , I wasn't aware that if the .net framework had been installed.  Thank you to every one that made a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by going to where SeleniumBasic was installed and doubleclicking the StartChrome.vbs and downloading the .net framework that was needed next.

Answer (score 1):

Cody was right on - see above -
Find where your selenium is installed and run the script.
C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Scripts\

Selenium could be in Programs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after doing the steps above, but there is a simple solution. Close Excel and reopen after performing the steps above.