# VBA using selenium not opening Google Chrome driver

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am quite new to VBA programming. I've written a code, and I've run it on my laptop and it worked, but once I've tried to run it on another laptop it didnt work. I've installed Google chrome on that another laptop, selenium has been installed as well. VBA reference was set the same. chromedriver.exe was replaced in selenium location and google chrome location with same chromedriver.exe as I used on previous laptop. But when I start to run the code, it doesnt work. It shows automation error as per screenshot

[image: Error message]

Here is the code:

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim Element As Object
Dim classElement As Object
Dim CD As New selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim Inv As selenium.WebElement

Sub VariablePO()

If Sheets("POcreation").Range("A2").Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set CD = New selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    CD.Start
    CD.Get "https://www.amazon.es/"
```

Could anyone advise possible solution?
Tomas

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself (edit your question) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: You might find the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918864

Comment: FWIW, your code runs fine here and opens the web page.  Are you sure you have the correct version of `ChromeDriver.exe` (matches your version of Chrome?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now. I've installed the MS .Net framework 3.5 and copy & paste the new chromedriver.exe into following paths:
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

The chrome driver I found here:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/

Comment: Exactly: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/0/3/703455ee-a747-4cc8-bd3e-98a615c3aedb/dotNetFx35setup.exe